# How to properly use jquery's tabs() function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails, jquery-ui-tabs

In my Grails app, I've got a GSP that looks a bit like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"><p>foo</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><p>bar</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"><p>zip</p></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

If I've understood it right, the jQuery tabs() call should make my "tabs" div look like a tabbed panel. Is that correct? If so, it's not working. It just renders as a normal ul.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just not bothering with the plugins for jQuery or jQueryUI. Instead just download the JS into your web-app/js folder. Then reference them using a traditional  tag but also using the grails "resource" taglib, ala....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery-ui.js')}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'jquery-ui.css')}" />
```

I like using plugins for many things, but for something as simple as a few JS libs, I just don't see enough value. There is a tiny bit of value in having the jQuery plugin as it provides a grails class that implements jQuery support for the 'remote*' taglibs (ala http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html), but I never use this anyways since I favor using jQuery directly.

Comment: Ok, I obtained the jquery and jquery-ui distros and put them in web-app/js. I amended the <g:javascript> tags to look like this: <g:javascript src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"/>
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"/>
However, it still appears NOT to work.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the scripts and not the CSS files, than you won't achieve anything.

To get a bundle of jQueryUi framework along with the CSS files and scripts use themeroller: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1):

[The tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is part of jQuery UI, which is an extension of jQuery. You need to install jquery UI on your page. See http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started to get you started with jQuery UI.

Comment: Yep, I've got jquery installed and confirmed that the basics work. That is, I got this much to work: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
</script>. So the alert() works, but the tabs() does not.

Comment: tabs is a part of *jQuery UI*, an **extension** to jQuery, which must be installed separately.

Comment: I have installed the jquery-ui plugin, and added "<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>" to my GSP. But the tabs() call still appears to have no effect. How can I confirm that the jquery-ui is properly installed?

Comment: Check the HTML source code of your page and see if it has a script tag which references the jquery-ui javascript file. Also check your developer console and see if your script generates an error or not.

Comment: I added a line "<g:javascript library="jquery-ui" plugin="jquery-ui"/>" to my GSP. This translates (correctly?) to the line "<script type="text/javascript" src="/octopus/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>". However, the tabs() line still appears to have no effect.

Comment: Aha! But... I see that there is no file named "jquery-ui.js". There is, however, a file called "jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.js" and "jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js". I suspect there's some very special way I am supposed to indicate the file name...?

Comment: I don't know about the grails tags. You could just rename the jquery-ui JS file to what grails tries to load. Also make sure that the custom jquery-ui JS file includes tha tabs widget.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3965/discussion-between-stephen-gross-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: I used the 'src' attribute to correctly specify the js file. Still, however, the tabs() call has no effect. How do I make sure that a <G:javascript> tag works?

Comment: Use the Firebug extension in Firefox to debug your javascript and use the firefox console to see if it has errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the help everyone. Here's what finally worked:

I obtained the jquery and jquery-ui distros and unzipped them directly into my web-app folders.

I used the following tags:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery-1.6.2.min"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css/smoothness',file:'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}" />
```

Note that I had forgotten to link to the appropriate css. Turns out it's a bit quirky to get right.

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationResources.groovy:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
    }
    jqueryui {
        resource url:'js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'
    }
}
```

In your gsp file, simply add this in the head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<r:require module="jqueryui" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```